# Are significance level and critical value the same thing in hypothesis testing?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

It seems to me that the alpha value is used behind both concepts. It is the cut off point where you determine whether to reject the null hypothesis or not.

So why are there two names for the same concept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not the same concept. They are, however, related.

For a simple null hypothesis, your significance level is the type I error rate that you choose, which is the long-run proportion of times you would reject the null hypothesis when the null hypothesis was true (and the other assumptions all held true).

(When the type I error rate is different in different parts of the null space, - as with a compound null hypothesis - it's the largest type I error rate under the null.)

The critical value is the value of the test statistic that marks the boundary of your rejection region. It's the least "extreme" value of the test statistic that is still in the rejection region (i.e. the value which would cause you to *just* reject). Any test statistic that is more extreme (less consistent with the null hypothesis in the direction of the alternative) will be in the rejection region and any that is less extreme (more consistent with the null than this) will not be in the rejection region.

The critical value is the most extreme (in the above sense) value available that would lead to a rejection region whose total probability under the null doesn't exceed the desired type I error rate. The actual type I error rate you get* with using that critical value will be your significance level.

(* or again, with a complex null, the largest of the rates you can get)

Comment: So the critical region should always be less than or equal to the type I error rate?

Comment: No. The critical region is something like say "$|t|\geq 2.3$" or "$F \geq 4.1$"  --- it's a set of values of the test statistic for which you will reject the null. You can't compare an interval like that to a type I error rate. You seem to be confusing the region with the probability of being within it when the null is true.

Comment: Alpha is used to define the size of the critical region, am I correct? And the critical value is just the numeric value at the cut off edge of the critical region, right?

Comment: The true significance level, alpha, is the probability of falling into the critical region *if the null hypothesis is true* (and further caveats apply, see my answer). This is sometimes called the "size" of the test, but it's only the size of the critical region if you're measuring the size of a region by that measure. The rest of your question is already completely addressed in my answer - but to reiterate, yes, the critical value is the  boundary of the critical region (/rejection region) ... which region includes its boundary.

Answer (score 0):

Type I/II error is supporting the hypothesis, thus they are called 'error', it is a common misconception that type I/II error causes the rejection. In fact, those result data that is falsely negative (Type I error), is recognized after you knowing the hypothesis is definitely true and not rejected. But critical value would causes the rejection of hypothesis, i dont know why thou